# How to delete duplicate data

Tags: sql, duplicates

How do I delete duplicate data? Data is in below format.

```
Id          name    firstname   time      age
13014495    abc     def         40:44.3   25
13022149    abc     def         40:44.3   25
```

Comment: ...And once we know RDBMS, we can close as a duplicate question, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DELETE FROM table_name A WHERE id > (
      SELECT min(id) FROM table_name B
      WHERE A.name= B.name and A.firstname = B.firstname and 
              A.time=B.time and A.age=B.age);
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this will delete the smallest id where the name and firstname columns are equal.

Comment: Hi, it's remove duplicate row on only two column combination, if you want more row than add more row in condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using Oracle:

```
    Delete from Your_Table
    Where 
    ROWID not in (Select min(ROWID) 
           from Your_Table               
           group by name, firstname ,time ,age         
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table 
where rowid > (SELECT min(rowid) 
               FROM table t2 
               group by t2.id,t2.name,t2.firstname,t2.time,t2.age);
```